# Infinite sequence $2^{n}-3 (n=2,3,...)$ contains no term divisible by 65

Tags: divisibility

Show that the infinite sequence $2^{n}-3 (n=2,3,...)$ contains infinitely many terms which are divisible by $5$ and infinitely many terms which are divisible by $13$, but no terms which are divisible by $65$

My attempt at this:-
By Fermat's theorem,
$$2^{4}\equiv 1\pmod5$$
Raising to the power k we get,
$$2^{4k}\equiv 1\pmod5$$

$$2^{4k+3}\equiv 8\pmod5$$
$$2^{4k+3}\equiv 3\pmod5$$
So, $5\mid 2^{n}-3\quad\forall \quad n=4k+3$ where $k$ is any non-negative integer.
Similarly, by Fermat's theorem
$$2^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$$ 
$$2^{12k}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$$
$$2^{12k+4}\equiv 16\pmod{13}$$
$$2^{12k+4}\equiv 3\pmod{13}$$
Therefore, $13\mid 2^{n}-3\quad\forall \quad n=12k+4$

How do I show that it contains no term which is divisible by 65?
Thank you!

Comment: MathJax hint:  when you want a multicharacter thing, enclose it in braces.  So \pmod {13} will give $\pmod {13}$

Comment: Thank you, sir! Will remember that.

Comment: It works everywhere-superscripts, subscripts, fractions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. By Fermat's little theorem, $2^n\pmod{5}$ and $2^n\pmod{13}$ depend only on $n\pmod{4}$ and $n\pmod{12}$, respectively. You've shown that $2^n\equiv 3 \pmod{5}$ if $n\equiv 3\pmod{5}$, but that's the opposite of what you want to prove; you want to show that $2^n\equiv 3\pmod{5}$ only if $n\equiv 3\pmod{5}$, and similarly for $13$. The result you'll get is that $2^n\equiv 3\pmod{5}$ only if $n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ and $2^n\equiv 3\pmod{13}$ only if $n\equiv 4\pmod{12}$. Those two conditions can clearly never be simultaneously satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Write $12k+4$ as $12n+4$ which  needs to be equal $4k+3$ which is odd unlike the former and $k,n$ are arbitrary   integers

Answer (score 0):

Note that $4k+3$ is of the form $12k+3, 12k+7,\text { or } 12k+11,$ never of the form $12k+4,$ so there are no numbers in common in your sequences.